# Let $A,B$ be subsequence limits of $\{a_n\}^\infty_n,\{b_n\}^\infty_n$ ,Prove that $A*B$ subsequence limit of $\{a_n*b_n\}^\infty_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $A,B$ be  subsequence limits of $\{a_n\}^\infty_n,\{b_n\}^\infty_n$ ,Prove that  $A*B$ subsequence limit of $\{a_n*b_n\}^\infty_n$

i need to prove if this true or false.

i think its false but i need to find a example that but i dont got any idea how ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

**It is false**. Take $a_n=b_n=(-1)^n$ and $-1$ is a subsequential limit of $a_n$ and $1$ is subsequential limit of $b_n$ but $-1$ is not a subsequential limit of $a_nb_n=1$.